# Is RegionOfAttraction() available for Multibody plants from pydrake?

Tags: python, drake

To get familiar with the Region of Attraction Codes i tried to estimate the RoA of an Acrobot for which i have an `urdf` description. Running these lines:

```
import numpy as np

from pydrake.all import DiagramBuilder, AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph, Parser, MultibodyPlant, Variable, Simulator, ConstantVectorSource, RegionOfAttraction, LinearSystem,LinearQuadraticRegulator,Saturation

import pydot
#%% prepare and load urdf
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.0)

parser = Parser(plant, scene_graph)
parser.AddModelFromFile("acrobot.urdf")

plant.Finalize()

#%% create down context
q=np.array([0.0,0.0])
qd=np.array([0.0,0.0])

stable_ctxt = plant.CreateDefaultContext() 
plant.SetPositions(stable_ctxt, q)
plant.SetVelocities(stable_ctxt, qd)

actuation_port = plant.get_actuation_input_port()
actuation_port.FixValue(stable_ctxt, 0)

#%% calc RoA
V = RegionOfAttraction(system=plant, context=stable_ctxt)
```

gave me this error:

```
SystemExit: Failure at systems/analysis/region_of_attraction.cc:126 in RegionOfAttraction(): condition 'xdot0.template lpNorm<Eigen::Infinity>() <= 1e-14' failed.
```

Which when looking at the comment in `region_of_attraction.cc:123` indicates that x0 is not a stable fixed point. However it should be stable for the `stable_ctxt` provided to `RegionOfAttraction()`.

Can the `RegionOfAttraction()` function be used to estimate the RoA of Multibody plants (and do they support conversion to Symbolic) or is there something else i have to consider/some obvious error in my thinking?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for asking and providing a minimal reproduction.  There were actually a lot of things going on in this example!

First, by calling `AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph` you've created a `MultibodyPlant` that is connected to a `SceneGraph`, but then passed only the plant into the `RegionOfAttraction` method without its `SceneGraph`.  It then complains because its geometry port is not connected.  One fix would be to do only:

```
plant = MultibodyPlant(time_step=0.0)
parser = Parser(plant)
parser.AddModelFromFile(
    FindResourceOrThrow("drake/examples/acrobot/Acrobot.urdf"))
plant.Finalize()
```

Second, the `RegionOfAttraction` code as written was assuming that you'd only pass in a closed-loop system (no input ports), like what you'd get from using LQR. So the input port "FixValue" assignment wasn't being copied to the symbolic plant.  It's reasonable to support the case of fixed input ports, too, so I've just [PR'd the fix](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/15425). Alternatively, you could get around this immediately by adding a `ConstantVectorSystem` for the input port and then passing the diagram (not the plant) into the `RegionOfAttraction` method.

Third, one must be mindful of what is reasonable to do in the symbolic `MultibodyPlant`.  We don't support symbolic inversion of the mass matrix (beyond the trivial cases); I don't think of this as a missing feature but rather a case we should avoid.  It's much much better to think about the dynamics in implicit form (see http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/lyapunov.html#ex:implicit).  Having said that, we *could* actually support 2x2 symbolic matrix inverses easily enough through the ABA ldlt call (I actually thought we had done that already).

Finally, the sums-of-squares tools used in `RegionOfAttraction` only support polynomial systems, and the Acrobot dynamics are not polynomial. You either want to substitute out the sin/cos terms, [as in this example](http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/lyapunov.html#ex:global_pend), or take a Taylor expansion of the dynamics around the fixed-point.  The symbolic tools support Taylor expansion, but I'm afraid I haven't added the tools that make the workflow very nice for this just yet by adding a method `TaylorExpand(System, Context)` that wraps the symbolic calls.  That also would be relatively easy and useful to do!

If there are particular missing pieces that would be of high value, then we could open an issue or even better I could try to help you contribute.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive and informative answer! I think from the perspective of someone who is still getting familiar with drake (and underactuated dynamics) it would be handy to be able to simply use `RegionOfAttraction` with `MultibodyPlant` objects obtained from `.urdf` files. As far as i understood from your answer this should be possible by formulating a different SOS programme using the implicit form & substitution of sin/cos. Maybe one could overload `RegionOfAttraction` for `MultiBodyPlant` objects and implement a RoA estimation the way you sketched out in your answer.

Comment: I am still in the process of getting familiar with drake & don't have enough time to contribute at the moment. If this changes and i think my work would be a useful contribution to drake i will get back to you, make a fork or send a pull request! :)

Comment: `RegionOfAttraction(MultibodyPlant)` is definitely on the roadmap.  ;-)